Can't Submit to App Store - All iOS and iPadOS apps must be built with the iOS 17 SDK or later
I am currently running XCode 14.3 on a 2015 Macbook using MacOS 12.6
I built an app using iOS 16.2 SDK and then was trying to deploy to App Store Connect where I get this error:
SDK version issue. This app was built with the iOS 16.2 SDK. All iOS and iPadOS apps must be built with the iOS 17 SDK or later, included in Xcode 15 or later, in order to be uploaded to App Store Connect or submitted for distribution. (ID: 9431bf9a-6b21-4270-932d-d01b23a47691)

To distribute my app, I need iOS 17. To have iOS 17 SDK, I need XCode 15 or later. To get XCode 15 or later, I need macOS 14.5 To get macOS 14.5, I would need a new machine since 14.5 is not supported for 2015 macbooks
Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can publish my app that don't require a new macbook for this situation?

You can find inexpensive older MacMinis on eBay.

It is possible to set up a CI pipeline that deploys changes you make directly to App Store Connect. I ran into the same issue and wasn't willing to upgrade my old MacBook just to keep updating my app. So I code on a old version of Xcode, and then when I push to GitHub it automatically pushes a new build to App Store Connect.

Sorry to say, but it's not possible to upload the app without building with SDK 17,
if you don't have the opportunity to buy a new Mac, you can go for a virtual Mac and try to build it from it.
I don't know if the solution I provide is helpful or not but there is no way without it.
